# After scrolling down to an anchor, while the page is loading, why does the page jump back to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To recreate this error:

1. Go to https://standardgates.com/dev.php with a cleared cache.
2. Quickly click either Driveway Gate, Security Fence, Automation Kit, or any of the navigation buttons at the top.
3. The page will scroll down. (scroll accuracy is irrelevant)
4. After one second or so the page jump backs to the top.

Note. The error only occurs until the page is fully loaded after a few seconds.

Any ideas? YOUR HELP IS VERY MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: After following your steps, step 4 is not happening for me. How is the click and anchor functionality implemented?

Comment: Thank you Rastalamm. Hmm try holding shift and refreshing the page in Chrome; on mobile the jump is very obvious. I removed everything that has to do with clicks, scrolling, and anchors in my JS files and the error still occurs. My best guess is something in my minified Jquery file here is causing the issue: https://standardgates.com/SG/js/js-above.js

Comment: UPDATE: It does not jump back to the top of the page. It jumps back to where you start the refresh on the page.